# How can you see the minimal relations on a quiver from its bimodule resolution?

Tags: rt.representation-theory, homological-algebra

Suppose that you are given an algebra $KQ/I$, coming from a quiver Q, of finite global dimension. Suppose also that you know its minimal bimodule resolution over its enveloping algebra. Can you get a minimal set of relations on your algebra from this resolution? Or is there more assumptions needed on $KQ/I$ in which it is possible?

Thank you!